# Error name '__file__' is not defined

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I have a complement (image_1) that works perfect. But I get an error by wanting to make a change.

[image]

I add the code of my two `.py` files.

I want to change this address: `"C:/Users/SENARA/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/RiegoSenara/LogoSenara.png"`

and use this:

```
 os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"LogoSenara.png")
```

This **works in the complemento.py**

```
 DialogBase, DialogType = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 
                                                      u'DialogoEjemplo1.ui'))
```

But it **doesn't work in qgis_minimal_plugin.py**

```
 self.action = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), u"LogoSenara.png"), 
                             QCoreApplication.translate('RiegoSenara', 'RiegoSenara'),
                             self.iface.mainWindow())
```

Image_2

[image]

This gives me the following error: `NameError: name __file__ is not defined`.
Other times it doesn't work at all.

Image_3

[image]

**FOLDER CODE COMPLEMENTO**

```
 from PyQt5 import uic
 from PyQt5.QtGui import *
 import os
 from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer
 from qgis.core import *
 from qgis.utils import *
 from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
 from pathlib import Path, PureWindowsPath

 #DialogBase, DialogType = 
 uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 
 u'DialogoEjemplo1.ui'), resource_suffix='')
 DialogBase, DialogType =   
 uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
 u'DialogoEjemplo1.ui'))

 class GeometryOperationDialog(DialogType, DialogBase):

def __init__(self,parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)

    self.Buscar.clicked.connect(self.loadLayers)
    self.Buscar1.clicked.connect(self.cargarnodos)

 #        self.loadLayers()
 #        self.cargarnodos()

def loadLayers(self):
    #Cargando el archivo con rutas de hojas cartográficas y archivos de texto del proyecto
    global Nuevaruta
    global Rutanueva
    self.file_path = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Cargar Lineas', './', filter="All Files(*.*);;Text Files(*.txt)")

    if self.file_path[0]:
       self.file_name = (self.file_path[0].split('/'))[-1]
       Narchivo=len(self.file_name)
       self.setWindowTitle("{} - Notepad".format(self.file_name))

       file_open = open(self.file_path[0], 'r+')
       Nuevaruta = Path(self.file_path[0])
       Cadena1=len(str(Nuevaruta))
       Nuevaruta2=str(Nuevaruta)
       fincadena=int(Cadena1-Narchivo-1)
       Rutanueva=Nuevaruta2 [0:fincadena]

#        Cargando un archivo txt wkt(000 000, 000 000),separado por tabulaciones con datos de lineas
    fn4=str(Nuevaruta)+str("?encoding=UTF-8&delimiter=\\t&wktField=wkt_geom&useheader=no&crs=epsg:5367&decimal=.")
    layer1 = QgsVectorLayer("file:///"+fn4,"Conduccion","delimitedtext")
    # Compruebe si la capa es válida 
    if not layer1 . isValid ():
        print ( "Capa TXT NO cargada" )
    fn5=Rutanueva
    fn5=fn5.rstrip()
    fn5=fn5+"\Tuberiasdr.shp"
    fn5=fn5.rstrip()
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer1, fn5, 'UTF-8', layer1.crs(), 'ESRI Shapefile')
    #Conviertiendo archivo lineas temporal en Shape para diametros
    fn9=Rutanueva
    fn9=fn9.rstrip()
    fn9=fn9+"\Tuberiadiam.shp"
    fn9=fn9.rstrip()
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer1, fn9, 'UTF-8', layer1.crs(), 'ESRI Shapefile')

        #Cargando Shape Lineas sdr
    fn6=Rutanueva
    fn6=fn6.rstrip()
    fn6=fn6+"\Tuberiasdr.shp"
    fn6=fn6.rstrip()
    layer4 = QgsVectorLayer(fn6, 'TuberiaSDR', 'ogr')
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer4)#Lo añado al mapa de capas
    #Cargando Shape Lineas diametro
    fn10=Rutanueva
    fn10=fn10.rstrip()
    fn10=fn10+"\Tuberiadiam.shp"
    fn10=fn10.rstrip()
    layer7 = QgsVectorLayer(fn10, 'TuberiaDiam', 'ogr')
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer7)#Lo añado al mapa de capas
    QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer7.id()).setItemVisibilityChecked(False)#Quita el check de la capa para que no se muestre
    QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer7.id()).setExpanded(False)

#CATEGORIZADO SDR
    #Esta funcion detecta el tipo de geometria
    def validatedDefaultSymbol(geometryType):
        symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(geometryType)
        if symbol is None:
            if geometryType == Qgis.Point:#== operador booleano true o false
                symbol = QgsMarkerSymbol()
            elif geometryType == Qgis.Line:
                symbol = QgsLineSymbol()
            elif geometryType == Qgis.Polygon:
                symbol = QgsFillSymbol()
        return symbol

    def makeSymbologyForRange(layer, min, max, title, color):#Funcion asigna color y ancho
        symbol = validatedDefaultSymbol(layer4.geometryType())
        symbol.setColor(color)
        symbol.setWidth(0.5)
        range = QgsRendererRange(min, max, symbol, title)#asigna min max tipo geometria y texto de titulo
        return range

    def applySymbologyFixedDivisions(layer, field):#Funcion crea rango categorizado
        rangeList = []#Crea un rango
        rangeList.append( makeSymbologyForRange(layer4, 14, 14, 'DR14', #Asigna valores a la lista del rango
    QColor("Green") ) )
        rangeList.append( makeSymbologyForRange(layer4, 17, 17, 'SDR17', #Asigna valores a la lista del rango
    QColor("Red") ) )
        rangeList.append( makeSymbologyForRange(layer4, 26, 26, 'SDR26',  
    QColor("Blue") ) )
        rangeList.append( makeSymbologyForRange(layer4, 32.5, 32.5, 'SDR32.5',  
    QColor("Yellow") ) )
        rangeList.append( makeSymbologyForRange(layer4, 41, 41, 'SDR41',  
    QColor("Black") ) )
        renderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer(field, rangeList)#Asigna parametros y titulo de columna con los valores
        renderer.setMode(QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer.Custom)#setmode Obsoleto QGIS 3.10 use classficationMethod en su lugar
        layer4.setRenderer(renderer)

    if layer4.isValid():
        applySymbologyFixedDivisions(layer4, "SDR")
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer4)

        #CATEGORIZADO DIAMETRO
    #Esta funcion detecta el tipo de geometria
    def validatedDefaultSymbol(geometryType):
        symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(geometryType)
        if symbol is None:
            if geometryType == Qgis.Point:#== operador booleano true o false
                symbol = QgsMarkerSymbol()
            elif geometryType == Qgis.Line:
                symbol = QgsLineSymbol()
            elif geometryType == Qgis.Polygon:
                symbol = QgsFillSymbol()
        return symbol

    def makeSymbologyForRange(layer, min, max, title, color):#Funcion asigna color y ancho
        symbol = validatedDefaultSymbol(layer7.geometryType())
        symbol.setColor(color)
        symbol.setWidth(0.5)
        range = QgsRendererRange(min, max, symbol, title)#asigna min max tipo geometria y texto de titulo
        return range

    def applySymbologyFixedDivisions(layer, field):#Funcion crea rango categorizado
        rangeList = []#Crea un rango
        rangeList.append( makeSymbologyForRange(layer7, 0, 57, '2"', #Asigna valores a la lista del rango
    QColor("Black") ) )
        rangeList.append( makeSymbologyForRange(layer7, 57, 70, '2.5"', #Asigna valores a la lista del rango
    QColor("darkMagenta") ) )
        rangeList.append( makeSymbologyForRange(layer7, 70, 85, '3"',  
    QColor("Yellow") ) )
        rangeList.append( makeSymbologyForRange(layer7, 85, 109, '4"',  
    QColor("Green") ) )
        rangeList.append( makeSymbologyForRange(layer7, 109, 160, '6"',  
    QColor("Blue") ) )
        rangeList.append( makeSymbologyForRange(layer7, 160, 208, '8"',  
    QColor("Red") ) )
        rangeList.append( makeSymbologyForRange(layer7, 208, 260, '10"',  
    QColor("Cyan") ) )
        rangeList.append( makeSymbologyForRange(layer7, 260, 308, '12"',  
    QColor("Magenta") ) )
        renderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer(field, rangeList)#Asigna parametros y titulo de columna con los valores
        renderer.setMode(QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer.Custom)#setmode Obsoleto QGIS 3.10 use classficationMethod en su lugar
        layer7.setRenderer(renderer)

    if layer7.isValid():
        applySymbologyFixedDivisions(layer7, "diametro")
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer7)

        #Agregando Etiquetas a la Tubería diametro
        for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
            layer_settings  = QgsPalLayerSettings()
            text_format = QgsTextFormat()

        text_format.setFont(QFont("Arial", 8))
        text_format.setSize(8)
        text_format.setColor(QColor('Black'))

        buffer_settings = QgsTextBufferSettings()
        buffer_settings.setEnabled(True)
        buffer_settings.setSize(0.10)
        buffer_settings.setColor(QColor('black'))

        text_format.setBuffer(buffer_settings)
        layer_settings.setFormat(text_format)

        layer_settings.fieldName = "diametro"
        layer_settings.placement = layer_settings.Line

        layer_settings.enabled = True

        layer_settings = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(layer_settings)
        layer4.setLabelsEnabled(True)
        layer4.setLabeling(layer_settings)
        layer4.triggerRepaint()

    #Agregando Etiquetas a la Tubería SDR
        for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
            layer_settings  = QgsPalLayerSettings()
            text_format = QgsTextFormat()

        text_format.setFont(QFont("Arial", 8))
        text_format.setSize(8)
        text_format.setColor(QColor('Black'))

        buffer_settings = QgsTextBufferSettings()
        buffer_settings.setEnabled(True)
        buffer_settings.setSize(0.10)
        buffer_settings.setColor(QColor('black'))

        text_format.setBuffer(buffer_settings)
        layer_settings.setFormat(text_format)

        layer_settings.fieldName = "SDR"
        layer_settings.placement = layer_settings.Line

        layer_settings.enabled = True

        layer_settings = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(layer_settings)
        layer7.setLabelsEnabled(True)
        layer7.setLabeling(layer_settings)
        layer7.triggerRepaint()

def cargarnodos(self):
    self.file_path = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Cargar Nodos', './', filter="All Files(*.*);;Text Files(*.txt)")

    if self.file_path[0]:
       self.file_name = (self.file_path[1].split('/'))[-1]

       self.setWindowTitle("{} - Notepad".format(self.file_name))

       file_open = open(self.file_path[0], 'r+')
       Nuevaruta1 = Path(self.file_path[0])

    #Cargando un archivo txt de Puntos
    fn4=str(Nuevaruta1)+str("?encoding=UTF-8&delimiter=\\t&xField=COORDEX&yField=COORDEY&useheader=no&crs=epsg:5367&decimal=.")
    layer5 = QgsVectorLayer("file:///"+fn4,"Nodos","delimitedtext")
    # Compruebe si la capa es válida 
    if not layer5 . isValid ():
        print ( "Capa Nodos NO cargada" )
    #QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer5)#Lo añado al mapa de capas
    #Conviertiendo archivo puntos temporal en Shape
    fn7=Rutanueva
    fn7=fn7.rstrip()
    fn7=fn7+"\Datos Puntos Qgis.shp"
    fn7=fn7.rstrip()
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer5, fn7, 'UTF-8', layer5.crs(), 'ESRI Shapefile')

    #Cargando Shape Puntos
    fn8=Rutanueva
    fn8=fn8.rstrip()
    fn8=fn8+"\Datos Puntos Qgis.shp"
    fn8=fn8.rstrip()
    layer6 = QgsVectorLayer(fn8, 'ObrasCiviles', 'ogr')
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer6)#Lo añado al mapa de capas
    QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer6.id()).setExpanded(False)
    #Cargando Shape Puntos 2
    fn11=Rutanueva
    fn11=fn11.rstrip()
    fn11=fn11+"\Datos Puntos Qgis.shp"
    fn11=fn11.rstrip()
    layer11 = QgsVectorLayer(fn11, 'Nodos', 'ogr')
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer11)#Lo añado al mapa de capas
    QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer11.id()).setItemVisibilityChecked(False)#Quita el check de la capa para que no se muestre
    # Definiendo la clase forma
    shape = QgsSimpleMarkerSymbolLayerBase

        # Creando un diccionario prara guardad campo,color, texto y forma
    land_class = {
        'PT': (QColor("blue"), 'PuenteTubo', shape. Arrow,3.5),
        'D': (QColor("yellow"), 'Desarenador', shape.Star,4),
        'TQ': (QColor("green"), 'TQuiebragradiente', shape.Diamond,3),
        'FT': (QColor("red"), 'Filtrado', shape.HalfSquare,3.5),
        'VT': (QColor("red"), 'Toma', shape.CrossFill,3),
        'R': (QColor("cyan"), 'Reservorio', shape.Pentagon,3.5),
    }
    # Crear una lista para almacenar propiedades de la simbologia
    categories = []
    # Iterate through the dictionary
    for classes, (colour, label, shape,tamaño) in land_class.items():
        # Define symbol based on layer's geometry
        symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer6.geometryType())
        # Set shape
        symbol.symbolLayer(0).setShape(shape)
        # Set Size
        symbol.setSize(tamaño)
        # Set colour
        symbol.setColor(QColor(colour))

        # Set the renderer properties    
        category = QgsRendererCategory(classes, symbol, label, shape)
        categories.append(category)
    # Field name
    expression = 'VALVULA'
    # Set the categorized renderer
    renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer(expression, categories)
    layer6.setRenderer(renderer)
    # Refresh layer
    layer6.triggerRepaint()
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer6)

    #Agregando Etiquetas a los Puntos
    for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
        layer_settings  = QgsPalLayerSettings()
        text_format = QgsTextFormat()

    text_format.setFont(QFont("Arial", 10))
    text_format.setSize(10)
    text_format.setColor(QColor('Red'))

    buffer_settings = QgsTextBufferSettings()
    buffer_settings.setEnabled(True)
    buffer_settings.setSize(0.05)
    buffer_settings.setColor(QColor('Red'))

    text_format.setBuffer(buffer_settings)
    layer_settings.setFormat(text_format)

    layer_settings.fieldName = """concat("PUNTO")"""
    layer_settings.isExpression=True#Agregado nuevo
    layer_settings.placement = 4

    layer_settings.enabled = True

    layer_settings = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(layer_settings)
    layer6.setLabelsEnabled(True)
    layer6.setLabeling(layer_settings)
    layer6.triggerRepaint()

    #Agregando Etiquetas a los Puntos Generales
    for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
        layer_settings  = QgsPalLayerSettings()
        text_format = QgsTextFormat()

    text_format.setFont(QFont("Arial", 10))
    text_format.setSize(10)
    text_format.setColor(QColor('Red'))

    buffer_settings = QgsTextBufferSettings()
    buffer_settings.setEnabled(True)
    buffer_settings.setSize(0.05)
    buffer_settings.setColor(QColor('Red'))

    text_format.setBuffer(buffer_settings)
    layer_settings.setFormat(text_format)

    layer_settings.fieldName = """concat("PUNTO", ' (', "VALVULA",')')"""
    layer_settings.isExpression=True#Agregado nuevo
    layer_settings.placement = 4

    layer_settings.enabled = True

    layer_settings = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(layer_settings)
    layer11.setLabelsEnabled(True)
    layer11.setLabeling(layer_settings)
    layer11.triggerRepaint()
```

**FOLDER CODE qgis_minimal_plugin**

```
 import os
 from PyQt5.QtGui import *
 from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
 from PyQt5.QtCore import *
 from .Complemento import GeometryOperationDialog
 #from .MapaQgis import Mapa
 #from .Prueba import Mensaje

 class MinimalPlugin:
 def __init__(self, iface):
    self.iface = iface

 def initGui(self):
    self.action = 



 QAction(QIcon("C:/Users/SENARA/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/
 default/python/plugins/RiegoSenara/LogoSenara.png"),
                      QCoreApplication.translate('RiegoSenara', 
 'RiegoSenara'),
                      self.iface.mainWindow())
 #        print (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"LogoSenara.png"))
 #        self.action = 
 QAction(QIcon(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),u"LogoSenara.png"),
 #                          QCoreApplication.translate('RiegoSenara', 
 'RiegoSenara'),
 #                          self.iface.mainWindow())

 #        self.action = 
 QAction(QIcon(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "LogoSenara.png")),
 #                           self.tr('RiegoSenara'),
 #                           self.iface.mainWindow())
 #        self.action = QAction(u'RiegoSenara', self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.action.triggered.connect(self.run)
    self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.action)

 #    def AbrirArchivo(self):
 #        filename=QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,"Selecione Hoja(s) 
 Cartograficas","",'*.txt')
 #        self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(filename)

def unload(self):
    self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.action)
    del self.action

    def run(self):
   #        QMessageBox.information(None, u'Minimal plugin',u'Do something 
   useful here')
    dialogo=GeometryOperationDialog()
    dialogo.exec_()                                                                                                                                 
 #        mens=Mensaje()
 #        MiClase=Mapa()
 #        MiClase.exec_()
```

**FOLDER CODE __init__**

```
 from .qgis_minimal_plugin import MinimalPlugin


 def classFactory(iface):
 return MinimalPlugin(iface)
```

Comment: It is the second, but for some reason when copying and pasting, the underscore does not appear. I can send you all the files.

Comment: Thanks.I edited my question. Please, can you help me solve my problem?

Comment: Is this being imported as a module? "Dunder" file is something internal in modules per https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/two_dunders.html.

Comment: I really do not understand. Should I define the variable in a separate module (py) and then call it? How do I do that?

Comment: I don't understand how to do it. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please somebody help me?

Comment: Check at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20510502/12248427

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was looking for. I found it in the WKT plugin code

```
 current_directory = 
 os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
 self.action = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join(current_directory, "icons", 
 "LogoSenara.png")),"&RiegoSenara", self.iface.mainWindow())
```